# How to check if a specific part of a text (string) is visible after HTML/Angular rendering?

Tags: css, angular, html

I am developing a website that uses some collapsible parts and if the text is really big, there is a "read more" link that allows the user to read all the content in a modal-dialog (bootstrap). The think is: I only want to show the "read more" link if the text is not fully displayed. However, the element that displays the text is already shown. Is there any way I can check if the text is fully visible?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367vW.png)

Here is the HTML/Angular snippet for it:

```html
<div class="collapse show" id="noticia{{i}}">
       <div class="sidebar-box">
         <p class="text-justify" [innerHTML]="noticia.noticia"></p>
         <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button"></a></p>
       </div>
       
       <!-- This I want to render ONLY IF noticia.noticia is NOT fully visible -->
       <p style="margin-left:5px;"><a (click)="noticiaSelecionada = noticia; modalTextoNoticia.show()" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Ler tudo...</a></p>
      
   <!-- IRRELEVANT CODE COMES HERE -->

</div>
```

These are the CSS snippets of this example:

```html
.sidebar-box {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-box .read-more { 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0; padding: 5px 0; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #eee);
}
```

Comment: The example that is shown in image makes use of the length of the text to hide rest of the content and add the "view more" link. You can `slice` the display and display the link if text length is more than whatever character you are looking for.

Comment: And use *ngIf to accomplish what @nircraft said.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it's a good design to detect if all content is visible but regardless, you can test if content in a div is overflowing with `if (el.offsetWidth == el.scrollWidth && 
el.offsetHeight == el.scrollHeight) {...}`.  But as this is only possible in JS (forget it, there is no CSS selector for overflowing), you'd have to go through the view and hide all links.  Very clunky.

Comment: I suspected since the beginning that I have to use something like "check the text length". Thanks you all.